# How to resolve Groovy conflict with Apache Common Logging?

Tags: java, logging, groovy, maven

This is my custom maven Groovy execution:

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-rc-5-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classpath>
          <element>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
          </element
        </classpath>
        <source>
          import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
          // ...
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
[...]
```

This is what Maven says:

```
[...]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0-rc-5-SNAPSHOT:execute (...) on project XXX: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException:
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
Invalid class loader hierarchy.  
You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, 
which is not allowed. 
(Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
Invalid class loader hierarchy.
[...]
```

I think that I understand why it happens, but how can I solve it?

Comment: I am curious, why do you use an old gmaven plugin instead of 1.3 (http://btilford.blogspot.com/2010/08/gmaven-13-is-out.html)?

Comment: Thanks, will use 1.3 from now on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to version 1.3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say exactly how to fix this without seeing your entire pom.xml file, but I'd suggest looking into the  tag. You could exclude the extra dependency with something like the following:

```
<plugin>
    ...
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <version>...</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>                        
                <exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I include `commons-logging` for my project. I can't exclude it entirely :) I need to exclude it just for this particular Groovy snippet. Possible?

Comment: Vincenzo, Your 'commons-httpd' also has a commons-logging dependency. So you have two 'commons-logging' dependencies clashing when you try to use commons-httpclient (the one you included, and the one it wants to use). What I'm suggesting you do is to exclude the one that commons-httpclient wants to use.

Comment: Exactly, but how to exclude it?

Answer (score 0):

Check who is importing that dependency with mvn dependency:tree and remove conflict.

Comment: I know who is importing this dependency, it's me :) I need this JAR in my project and I can't exclude it. I just want Gmaven not to import it again. Can I do this?